# Calling external API on the Alexa Developer Console with Python Code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I need some help with the Alexa Development Console. I want to implement a new Alexa Skill with an external API where you can trade or sell stocks with Alexa. I used to Python for coding and requests & json library.

Whenever I try to test my code, Alexa says something like "What do you mean" or reads out a Wikipedia article (Still haven't used AWS, but how can I link the API with AWS?). Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code here:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# This sample demonstrates handling intents from an Alexa skill using the Alexa Skills Kit SDK for Python.
# Please visit https://alexa.design/cookbook for additional examples on implementing slots, dialog management,
# session persistence, api calls, and more.
# This sample is built using the handler classes approach in skill builder.
import logging
import ask_sdk_core.utils as ask_utils
import requests
import json

from ask_sdk_core.skill_builder import SkillBuilder
from ask_sdk_core.dispatch_components import AbstractRequestHandler
from ask_sdk_core.dispatch_components import AbstractExceptionHandler
from ask_sdk_core.handler_input import HandlerInput

from ask_sdk_model import Response

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def getResponseFromAPI():
    slots = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots
    side = slots["side"].value
    api_key = "YOUR API KEY" # enter your API key here 
    if side == "purchase":
        side = "buy"
    stock = slots["stock"].value
    quantity = slots["quantity"].value
    if stock == "TL0":
        isin = "CA88162R1091"  # for Tesla CDR Reg S
            
    url = "https://paper-trading.lemon.markets/v1/orders/"
    response = requests.post(
            url,
               data=json.dumps({
              "isin": isin, # enter the isin
              "expires_at": "2022-04-28", 
              "side": side,  # buy or sell 
              "quantity": quantity, # amount of stocks user wants to buy/sell
              "venue": "XMUN",}),
              headers={"Authorization": api_key}) 
    print(response.status_code)
    json_data = response.json()
    isin_result = json_data['isin']
    return isin_result
    

    # class stock_dict = [
    #    {"Tesla" : "TL0",
    #     "Apple" : "APPL",
    #    "stock name" : "ISIN"
    #   }]
    # the_stock = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.number.value
    # the_fact = stock_dict[the_stock]


class LaunchRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Skill Launch."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool

        return ask_utils.is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        logging.info("LaunchRequest was trigerred")
        trade = getResponseFromAPI()
        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(f"{isin_result}.Trading done. Would you like to continue trading?")
                .ask("Would you like to continue trading with the lemon markets API? If so, please place a trade.")
                .response
        )
    


class MarketOrderIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Market Order Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("MarketOrderIntent")(handler_input) 

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        
        speak_output = "Welcome! You're here to buy or sell stocks with the lemon.markets API. Is that correct? What would you like to do?"
        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                # .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
                .response
        )

class HelpIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Help Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.HelpIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "You can say hello to me! How can I help?"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )


class CancelOrStopIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Single handler for Cancel and Stop Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return (ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.CancelIntent")(handler_input) or
                ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.StopIntent")(handler_input))

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "Goodbye!"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .response
        )

class FallbackIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Single handler for Fallback Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.FallbackIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        logger.info("In FallbackIntentHandler")
        speech = "Hmm, I'm not sure. You can say Hello or Help. What would you like to do?"
        reprompt = "I didn't catch that. What can I help you with?"

        return handler_input.response_builder.speak(speech).ask(reprompt).response

class SessionEndedRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Session End."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_request_type("SessionEndedRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response

        # Any cleanup logic goes here.

        return handler_input.response_builder.response


class IntentReflectorHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """The intent reflector is used for interaction model testing and debugging.
    It will simply repeat the intent the user said. You can create custom handlers
    for your intents by defining them above, then also adding them to the request
    handler chain below.
    """
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_request_type("IntentRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        intent_name = ask_utils.get_intent_name(handler_input)
        speak_output = "You just triggered " + intent_name + "."

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                # .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
                .response
        )


class CatchAllExceptionHandler(AbstractExceptionHandler):
    """Generic error handling to capture any syntax or routing errors. If you receive an error
    stating the request handler chain is not found, you have not implemented a handler for
    the intent being invoked or included it in the skill builder below.
    """
    def can_handle(self, handler_input, exception):
        # type: (HandlerInput, Exception) -> bool
        return True

    def handle(self, handler_input, exception):
        # type: (HandlerInput, Exception) -> Response
        logger.error(exception, exc_info=True)

        speak_output = "Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again."

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )





# The SkillBuilder object acts as the entry point for your skill, routing all request and response
# payloads to the handlers above. Make sure any new handlers or interceptors you've
# defined are included below. The order matters - they're processed top to bottom.


sb = SkillBuilder()

sb.add_request_handler(LaunchRequestHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(MarketOrderIntentHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(HelpIntentHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(CancelOrStopIntentHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(FallbackIntentHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(SessionEndedRequestHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(IntentReflectorHandler()) # make sure IntentReflectorHandler is last so it doesn't override your custom intent handlers

sb.add_exception_handler(CatchAllExceptionHandler())

lambda_handler = sb.lambda_handler()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sounds like the skill is failing ... my usual first step in cases like this is the add try/except to see exactly where the skill is failing.